# Sed / Awk parsing lines between certain charcters

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I'm having hard time trying to parse the following:

Current assigned information to variable is:

```
position: 170.198.19.170/net1
position: 170.198.19.165/rxy
position: take1234/net 
position: imwell/net3
position: xyz/444
position: 170.198.82.142/net
position: whoareu/net
```

I want to print all charcters between "Position:"  and  the Slash "/" minus the spaces and print them on a new line

So the end result should be :

```
170.198.19.170
170.198.19.16
take1234
imwell
xyz  
170.198.82.142

whoareu
```

Can someone help please. Try some TR and Sed replace but just not getting it.

Thanking u in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
echo "$variablename" | sed "s/position:/\npostion:/g" | cut -d"/" -f 1| cut -d " " -f 2 | sed '/^$/d'
```

This is updated answer where 'position:' occurs only once on ethe line, and I did it without using `cut`

```
echo "$variablename" | sed "s/position: //" | sed "s/\//\n/" | sed -n '2~2!p'
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks this is working .. Though I hate to use the cut command  There must another way to do this

Comment: Given the input data, why are the `sed`s necessary at all?  This can be done purely with [`cut` (see my answer)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22051754/2113226)

Comment: when I posted this file with inputs did not have all 'position:' on the beginning of the line, it was edited after I posted this. About cutting    cut    out of this I will try... so hold on for now

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

```
awk -F '[:/ ]+' '$2=="position"{print $3}' file
170.198.19.170
170.198.19.165
take1234
imwell
xyz
170.198.82.142
whoareu
```

**EDIT:**

```
awk -F ':' '$1 ~ /position/{gsub(/ +|\/.*$/, ""); print $2}' file
```

Comment: This one works fine for me too.  If you're having problems, please be specific.  We can't help you if you don't tell us what's wrong.

Comment: This one doesn't work for me.  Ubuntu 12.04, bash 4.2.25, GNU Awk 3.1.8.  I don't know enough `awk` to quickly debug.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: `$2` should be `$1`, and `$3` should be `$2`.

Comment: @anubhava - the edited version still doesn't quite work for me.  The `/` chars are removed, but not the text after them.  For example the first line of output is `170.198.19.170net1`

Comment: @anubhava - looks good now.  This seems to be sufficient for the input data too: `awk -F '[ /]' '{print $2}' <<< "$input"`

Comment: But you want to print only when `position` text is found.

Comment: @theuniverseisflat: Hope this edited awk command works out for you.

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming your data is in a variable called `input`**:

Using `cut`:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f2 <<< "$input" | cut -d/ -f1
170.198.19.170
170.198.19.165
take1234
imwell
xyz
170.198.82.142
whoareu
$
```

---

An interesting pure-bash way using `mapfile` (requires [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) >= 4.0) and parameter expansions on the resulting array elements.  The end result is your required data in the elements of the array `a`:

```
$ mapfile -t a <<< "$input"
$ a=("${a[@]%%/*}")
$ a=("${a[@]##*: }")
$ echo ${a[@]}
170.198.19.170 170.198.19.165 take1234 imwell xyz 170.198.82.142 whoareu
$
```

---

Another pure-bash way, using the `IFS` variable to separate on both  and `/`:

```
$ while IFS=" /" read _ x _; do echo "$x"; done <<< "$input"
170.198.19.170
170.198.19.165
take1234
imwell
xyz
170.198.82.142
whoareu
$
```

---

Probably the shortest with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F '[ /]' '{print $2}' <<< "$input"
170.198.19.170
170.198.19.165
take1234
imwell
xyz
170.198.82.142
whoareu
$
```

Comment: @theuniverseisflat - both methods work for me.  What, if any errors do you see?  What version of `bash` are you using?  Is your input data in a file, or something else?

Comment: this is working for me :  sed 's/position:[ ]*/\n/g' | sed -e 's/\/.*//

Comment: @theuniverseisflat - I see your input data is simply stored in a flat variable and not a file as I had assumed.  So I have changed my answers to accept input from the variable via a bash here-string

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
awk '{sub(/\/.*/,"",$2); print $2}' file
```

```
$ awk '{sub(/\/.*/,"",$2); print $2}' << EOF
position: 170.198.19.170/net1
position: 170.198.19.165/rxy
position: take1234/net 
position: imwell/net3
position: xyz/444
position: 170.198.82.142/net
position: whoareu/net
EOF
170.198.19.170
170.198.19.165
take1234
imwell
xyz
170.198.82.142
whoareu
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/position:[ ]*/\n/g' t|sed 's_/[a-zA-Z0-9]*__g'|sed '/^\s*$/d'
```

Will do the trick.

**How This works?**

1. Convert `position:` to newlines.
2. Remove everything beyond `/` **in** a line.
3. Delete empty lines.

And you get what you want.

**To appreciate why this was done**, note that OP had the following as the input initially :

> position: 170.198.19.170/net1 position: 170.198.19.165/rxy position:
>   take1234/net position: imwell/net3 position: xyz/444 position:
>   170.198.82.142/net position: whoareu/net position:

Making it *much more harder* than the relatively trivial input now.

```
aman@apollo:~/entire-src/py/imgdata$ cat t
position: 170.198.19.170/net1 position: 170.198.19.165/rxy position: take1234/net position: imwell/net3 position: xyz/444 position: 170.198.82.142/net position: whoareu/net position:
aman@apollo:~/entire-src/py/imgdata$ sed 's/position:[ ]*/\n/g' t|sed 's_/[a-zA-Z0-9]*__g'|sed '/^\s*$/d'
170.198.19.170 
170.198.19.165 
take1234 
imwell 
xyz 
170.198.82.142 
whoareu 
aman@apollo:~/entire-src/py/imgdata$
```

---

For the **updated input**, `cut -f2 -d' ' t|sed 's_/[a-zA-Z0-9[:punct:]]*__g'` will work. Here `t` is the name of the file which stores the pattern.

Comment: Why run sed three times?

Comment: @ghoti I tried using the `-e` option but it wasn't working. Plus this looks neater imo.

Comment: Only the first part of your command is working and u had an extra t in that .. I just need to know now the command to find the forward slash  "/" and delet anything after it I think

Comment: @theuniverseisflat `t` is the file in which your **initial** input was stored as can be seen from the dump I have pasted (`cat t`)

Comment: So not in the example I have provided .. I have another entry  170.198.26.69/nj-dts-40    << after executing ur command I get 170.198.26.69-dts-40  So it works for the sample data I provided but not when there i a dash

Comment: @theuniverseisflat Updated, should work now. (see the answer for updated input)

Comment: this worked for me sed 's/position:[ ]*/\n/g' | sed -e 's/\/.*//

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
$ sed -ne '/^position: /{;s/^position: //;s:/.*::;p;}' <<< "$input"
170.198.19.170
170.198.19.165
take1234
imwell
xyz
170.198.82.142
whoareu
$
```

Or awk:

```
$ awk '/^position: /{sub(/^position: /, ""); sub(/\/.*/,""); print;}' <<< "$input"
170.198.19.170
170.198.19.165
take1234
imwell
xyz
170.198.82.142
whoareu
$
```

Or just using bash:

```
$ while read one two ; do [ "$one" = "position:" ] && echo "${two%%/*}" ; done <<< "$input"
170.198.19.170
170.198.19.165
take1234
imwell
xyz
170.198.82.142
whoareu
$
```

There are MANY ways to skin this cat.

Comment: All three work for me.  What did they do instead of working, when you tried them?

Comment: @theuniverseisflat - all 3 work for me.  Is your input data in a file called `file`, as required by these examples?

Comment: this worked for me thanks ::   sed 's/position:[ ]*/\n/g' | sed -e 's/\/.*//

Comment: I've adjusted my answer to take input from a variable instead of a file.  All the commands are the same -- the only difference is changing `file` to `<<< "$input"`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all >> In between you commands and other I came up with this

```
sed 's/position:[ ]*/\n/g' | sed -e 's/\/.*//
```

So thanks again !!!!

Comment: Sorry the command did not come out right - This is the right command : sed 's/position:[ ]*/\n/g' | sed -e 's/\/.*//

Comment: Where is your input variable?

Comment: This won't work, you aren't closing the quotes for the second sed script.  Also, how does it handle input lines that don't start with the word `position:` ?

Answer (score 0):

Using [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) without spawning an external process:

```
$ foo="position: 170.198.19.170/net1
> position: 170.198.19.165/rxy
> position: take1234/net
> position: imwell/net3
> position: xyz/444
> position: 170.198.82.142/net
> position: whoareu/net"

$ echo "${foo//position: /}"
170.198.19.170/net1
170.198.19.165/rxy
take1234/net
imwell/net3
xyz/444
170.198.82.142/net
whoareu/net
```